# Count how many times esper receives different inherit events.

Tags: esper

I'm new using Esper and I have been able to manage with it until now. There is something that I can't find solution and I have tried to find everywhere with no success.

I have three Classes extending one to other one.
Using Esper Online:

```
create schema A(symbol string, price double);
create schema B() inherits A;
create schema C() inherits B;
```

Now I want to count how many of each events in a time window of 2 seconds I have received, using the next EPL statement:

```
select COALESCE(a.symbol,b.symbol,c.symbol) as symbol, count(a) as total_a, count(b) as total_b, count(c) as total_c from pattern [every a=A or every b=B or every c=C]#time(2 seconds) group by COALESCE(a.symbol,b.symbol,c.symbol);
```

And I run the next events:

```
A={symbol='X', price=1}
B={symbol='X', price=1}
C={symbol='X', price=1}
C={symbol='X', price=1}
```

The problem is when I send a B event, it counts a B event and an A event due to inheritance , and obviously if I send a C event it counts a C a B and also an A event.

I have used the pattern-level annotation @SuppressOverlappingMatches it works  with inheritances, but Time Windows doesn't work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
select count(*, typeof(a)='A') as cnt_a, count(*, typeof(a)='B') as cnt_b,
  count(*, typeof(a)='C') as cnt_c from A#time(2 sec) as a
```